# Django best practice with foreign key queries

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class SubCatergory(models.Model):
    parent_category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

views.py

```
def all_products(request):
c = Category.objects.all()
s = SubCatergory.objects.all()

return render_to_response('all_products.html',
                          {'c':c, 's':s})
```

all_products.html

```
{% for category in c %}
    <h1>{{ category.name }}</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for sub in s  %}
        {% if category.id == sub.parent_category.id %}
            <li>{{ sub.name }}</li>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Just wondering if above is best practice for foreign key queries. I'm filtering at the template level (if category.id == sub...), should I move this to the model or view level instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there's only ever one depth of subcategory, the following code shouldn't be a problem:

```
{% for category in c %}
    <h1>{{ category.name }}</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for sub in category.subcatergory_set.all %}
            <li>{{ sub.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

But there are some optimization tricks to reduce query count as you'd be doing a query per loop. I'm trying to think of one now.

Actually, I'm starting to think this is an interesting question: best practice?

Your method uses 2 queries. My method is using django practices, but does multiple queries.

To prevent multiple queries, you'd essentially have to do the same thing you've done in your template in your view, namely iterating over `SubCatergory`, pulling their IDs in python and grouping each ID set onto an attribute on `Category`.

I don't know the answer to this one.

Comment: Thanks, there is only one depth of subcategory.

Answer (score 2):

I think that one good practice here would be to create a template tag for this job. That way you can cache the rendered template and only hit the database at the first render.

First, create the template tag inside your app

templatetags/show_categories_list.py

```
from django.core.cache import cache

@register.simple_tag
def show_categories_list():
    cached = cache.get('CATEGORIES_LIST_CACHE_KEY', None)
    if cached is None:
        categories = Category.objects.all()
        rendered = render_to_string('all_categories.html', {'categories': categories})
        cache.set('CATEGORIES_LIST_CACHE_KEY', rendered)
        return rendered
    return cached
```

Then, create the template to be used

all_categories.html

```
{% for category in categories %}
    <h1>{{ category.name }}</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for sub in category.subcategory_set.all %}
            <li>{{ sub.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Override the save method in your models so it will delete the categories list cache entry (forcing it to be rendered at the next request, this could also be placed at the (pre|post)_save signal):

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cache.delete('CATEGORIES_LIST_CACHE_KEY')
        return super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class SubCatergory(models.Model):
    parent_category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cache.delete('CATEGORIES_LIST_CACHE_KEY')
        return super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And finally use it like this:

base.html

```
{% load show_categories_list %}
{% show_categories_list %}
```

You can also add a timeout to the cache entry, so you don't have to override the save method in your models, but you will have to wait the timeout so it can be rendered again.

Some useful references:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#shortcut-for-simple-tags
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/signals/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a reference in the other direction as well, so that each Category would reference a list of SubCategories? Then you'll be able to write two nested loops: an outer loop for categories and in inner loop for iterating over the subcategories in each category.

Comment: this is the right idea, but note that django does this automatically for you. It automatically creates a 'reverse relation' for every foreign key pointing at a model, which is (if you don't explicitly change it) the name of the related model plus "_set".
See the following link for more information: 
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects

Comment: It's true that django gives you an API to query the the reverse relationship. How ever, using the reverse relationship to retrieve the related models, will still result in an extra SQL query which can be a huge performance hit if done multiple times (i.e. in a loop). To avoid this, one might want to denormalize the relationship so that in the above case, one would save references to the SubCategories on each Category.