# django best practice query foreign key

Tags: django

I am trying to understand the best way to structure queries in django to avoid excessive database hits.
This is similar to the question: [Django best practice with foreign key queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030131/django-best-practice-with-foreign-key-queries), but involves greater 'depth' in the queries.

My situation:
models.py

```
class Bucket(models.Model):
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category')

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class SubCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

class SubSubCategory(models.Model):
    subcat = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory)
```

views.py

```
def showbucket(request, id):
    bucket = Bucket.objects.prefetch_related('categories',).get(pk=id)
    cats = bucket.categories.prefetch_related('subcategory_set__subsubcategory_set',)
    return render_to_response('showbucket.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and relevant template:

```
{% for c in cats %}
    {{c}}
    <ul>
    {% for d in c.subcategory_set.all %}
        <li>{{d}}</li>
        <ul>
        {% for e in d.subsubcategory_set.all %}
            <li>{{e}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Despite the use of prefetch_related(), I seem to be hitting the database each time the top two for statements are evaluated, e.g. {% for c in cats %}, (at least I believe so from reading the debug_toolbar).  Other ways I've tried have ended up with (C x D x E) number of database hits.  Is this something inherently wrong with my use of prefetch, queries, or models?  What is the best way in Django to access database objects with a "depth > 1" so-to-speak?

Answer (score 3):

Use select_related() instead:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related

```
bucket = Bucket.objects.select_related('categories',).get(id=id)
cats = bucket.categories.select_related('subcategory_set__subsubcategory_set',)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, i found out there's a couple things going on here:

First, my current understanding on select_related vs prefetch_related:

[select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) follows foreign-key relationships, causing larger result sets but means that later use of FK won't require additional database hits.  It is limited to FK and one-to-one relationships.

prefetch_related() does a separate lookup for each relationship and joins them in python, and is means to be used for many-to-many, many-to-one, and GenericRelation and GenericForeignKey.

By the book, I should be using prefetch(), as I was not 'following' the Foreign Keys.
That's what I had understood going into this, but my template seemed to be causing additional queries when evaluating the given for loops in the template, even when I added the use of {with} tags.

At first, I had thought I had discovered something similar to [this issue](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar/issues/187), but I am unable to replicate when I built out my simplified example.  I switched from using the debug toolbar to direct checking using the following template code (in the article Tracking SQL Queries for a Request using Django by Karen Tracey, I would link but am link-limited):

```
{% with sql_queries|length as qcount %}
{{ qcount }} quer{{ qcount|pluralize:"y,ies" }}
{% for qdict in sql_queries %}
{{ qdict.sql }} ({{ qdict.time }} seconds)
{% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

Using this method, I am only seeing 5 queries for using pre-fetch() (7 with debug_toolbar), and queries grow linearly when using select_related() (with +2 for debug_toolbar), which I believe is expected.

I will gladly take any other advice/tools on getting a handle on these types of issues.